# Magento add sort by bestseller option in toolbar

Tags: magento

I am looking for bestseller option in sort by section in toolbar on category page(magento EE version).I have search each and everything but nothing found.Is anyone has idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of Magento Enterprise. But this [post](https://pratikkhamar.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/magento-sort-by-best-seller-in-toolbar/) was worked for Magento Community Edition.
Not sure it works with Magento EE.